How I can use iop-pyhton package on android?
I am using a packge name "iop-python" for my kivy app. It is not present inside the pythonforandroid for compilation so i code a recipe for it. But I am having issue in writing the recipe.
iop-python package git repo link:
https://github.com/BukiOffor/hydra-python-api/tree/main
I am having to compile this package using pythonforandroid
I am having to compile this iop-python using pythonforandroid so it will run on android
Recipe code
import os
from pythonforandroid.recipe import PythonRecipe
from pythonforandroid.toolchain import shprint
import sh
from os.path import join

class HydraPythonApiRecipe(PythonRecipe):
    version = 'main'
    url = 'https://github.com/BukiOffor/hydra-python-api/archive/main.tar.gz'
    
    # Define dependencies for building the Python package
    depends = ['python3', 'setuptools', 'wheel', 'rust']

    # Define Python-specific dependencies
    python_depends = ['maturin', 'tomli']

    def build_arch(self, arch):
        super().build_arch(arch)
        
        # Ensure setuptools is installed
        shprint(sh.pip3, 'install', 'setuptools')

        # Set up Rust toolchain for the specific target architecture
        rust_target = 'armv7-linux-androideabi' if 'armeabi' in arch.arch else arch.arch
        shprint(sh.rustup, 'target', 'add', rust_target)

        # Define the build directory based on architecture
        build_dir = self.get_build_dir(arch.arch)

        # Run maturin to build the Python wheel using Rust
        # Ensure you're using the correct target for cross-compilation
        env = self.get_recipe_env(arch)  # Get the appropriate environment
        shprint(sh.maturin, 'build', '--release', '--target', rust_target, '--out-dir', build_dir, _env=env)

        # Install the resulting wheel
        wheel_path = join(build_dir, f'hydra_python_api-{self.version}-py3-none-any.whl')  # Update to match your wheel name pattern
        shprint(sh.pip3, 'install', wheel_path)

    def get_recipe_env(self, arch):
        """
        Set up the build environment for the architecture, including Rust flags.
        """
        env = super().get_recipe_env(arch)
        
        # Set Rust-related environment variables for cross-compilation
        rust_target = 'armv7-linux-androideabi' if 'armeabi' in arch.arch else arch.arch
        env['CARGO_BUILD_TARGET'] = rust_target
        env['RUSTFLAGS'] = '--sysroot={}'.format(self.ctx.ndk_sysroot(arch))

        return env

    def install_dependencies(self):
        """
        Ensure all Python dependencies are installed from requirements.txt.
        This should be called before building.
        """
        shprint(sh.pip3, 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt')

# Register the recipe
recipe = HydraPythonApiRecipe()

